# Changing Accordion Color On Click Through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to change the header color of an accordion menu through a click event using a Javascript function. As I have it now the color will change on my first click but not the second.

my HTML accordion setup:

```
<div id ="accordion">
    <a class="tab" onclick="highlightHead(this, '#2E8AE6')" href="javascript:AccordionControls('headerOne')">Header One</a>
    <div id="headerOne"  class="tab-content" style="display:none">This is my first header paragraph</div>

    <a class="tab" onclick="highlightHead(this, '#2E8AE6')" href="javascript:AccordionControls('headerTwo')">Header Two</a>
    <div id="headerTwo" class="tab-content" style="display:none">This is my second header paragraph</div>
</div>
```

my Javascript function:

```
function highlightHead(headerID, color)
{
    if (headerID.style.backgroundColor  = "#000033") {

        headerID.style.backgroundColor = color;

    } else {

        headerID.style.backgroundColor = "#000033";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put === to your if statement instead of =

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "==" not "=" as it is essentially asking whether it is equal not setting it.

```
 function highlightHead(headerID, color)
{
    if (headerID.style.backgroundColor  == "#000033") {

        headerID.style.backgroundColor = color;

    } else {

        headerID.style.backgroundColor = "#000033";

    }
}
```